# Item controls in wpf mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am working on wpf and using an ItemsControl to represent a list of class on the UI.

My code is like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UsecaseListItems}" >

            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay,IsAsync=True}"

                                Margin="2,5"/>
                        <Button  Content="{Binding UsecaseName}"

                                Margin="2,5"/>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>

            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        </ItemsControl>
```

Now I wand to add a header to both the columns (Select all and UseName) at the top of the list. How can I do it??

Comment: Since each item's template has it's own wrap panel, I think talking about "columns" is a misstatement. Especially that the content of your button is bound. Perhaps you should consider using a `ListView` instead of `ItemsControl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution (Not a good one but I supposed worse design are also possible) and please change `bindings` in your code:

***XAML:***

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=list}" >
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">                   
                <Border BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Content="Select All" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        <Button Content="User name" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <Border BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="LightGray">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent},Path=ItemsSource}">

                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <WrapPanel>
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=DeviceState,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay,IsAsync=True}"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100" Margin="2,5"/>
                                    <Button  Content="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100" Margin="2,5"/>
                                </WrapPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>

                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
</ItemsControl>
```

***Output***

[image: list]

Why do you want buttons as header? can't you just put buttons outside the `ItemsControl`?

Answer (score -1):

It is preferable to go with `ListView` control instead of `ItemsControl` for what you need.

Here is the sample. .

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="checkboxHeaderTemplate">
            <CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked">  //add command for MVVM
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxCell">
            <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" >                    
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonCell">
            <Button  Content="{Binding Path=UsecaseName, Mode=TwoWay}" >
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UsecaseListItems}" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource checkboxHeaderTemplate}"
                                        CellTemplate="{StaticResource CheckBoxCell}" Width="auto">
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource checkboxHeaderTemplate}"
                                        CellTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonCell}" Width="auto">
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Hope that helps.